# TensorFlow Inception Model Can't See Files In Folder

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I hope everyone is having a great day.

I'm attempting to train a convnet for fun, but the TensorFlow Inception v3 model doesn't find any files within my folders even though they are there.

I get this error when trying to train it:

```
Looking for images in 'evening_star'
No files found
Looking for images in 'morning_star'
No files found
No valid folders of images found at /tf_files/image_recognition
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be occurring?

Comment: Can you try os.listdir('foldername') and see what python thinks is in that folder?

Comment: os.listdir('morning_star') and on.listdir('evening_star') shows all the .png photos saved in the folder... The plot thickens

Answer (score 4):

check out your files extension. I had the same problem because all my images were "png". If you have a look into the script "retrain.py", you'll see:

`extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG']`

just modify it to allow "png" as well and problem solved:

`extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'png', 'PNG']`

hope this help you!